# Joomla Category Blog Breaks CSS Framework Responsiveness

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, materialize

When I create a "Category Blog" page, it ruins my CSS framework. I've tried this with Bootstrap 4, Bootstrap 3 and MaterializeCSS. The same thing happens each time.

The left column displays correctly, containing the category blog article previews. The right column, however, is moved below the left column.

Here's the code I'm using when I try bootstrap:

```
        <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 mt-4">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="main_one" />
                <jdoc:include type="component" />
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="main_two" /> 
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 mt-5" id="side">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="side_one" /> 
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="side_two" /> 
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="side_three" /> 
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I've tried every Joomla setting I can think of, and even removed a bunch of classes from the generated page using the developer tools, and I haven't been able to isolate the problem. I'm fairly new to Joomla and any help would be much appreciated.

The way it should work is visible here: thepedanticpolymath.com/index.php

The problem is visible here: thepedanticpolymath.com/index.php/home/test

P.S. I have searched for this problem, and I do see that others have asked it - but none of the questions I've found have any answers at all.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Sure. I had it “offline” since I’m not anywhere close to being done with it.

Comment: The problem is: http://thepedanticpolymath.com/index.php/home/test  just go to the index for how it should behave.

Comment: It's confusing to see where those sections fall.  you might wrapping the module positions with a div with IDs or classes

Comment: Thanks for the help YellowWebMonkey. I remembered that a different site I’m using Joomla on doesn’t have this problem - but uses Zurb’s Foundation 6. I’m going to use that site’s template and see if it solves the issue. At least then I’ll know if it’s a Joomla! Issue, or that Joomla! Is applying a class that conflicts with both Bootstrap and MaterializeCSS.